# Disabling automatic back pressure in Storm

Tags: apache-storm

In previous versions of Storm, it seems it was possible to disable *automatic back pressure* by setting `topology.backpressure.enable` to `false`. However, with recent versions of Storm (I am using Storm 2.1.0), this option has been removed (or not fully yet). In the source code of [`Config`](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v2.1.0/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/Config.java), I saw the following snippet of code:

```
/**
 * Whether to enable backpressure in for a certain topology.
 *
 * @deprecated: In Storm 2.0. Retained for enabling transition from 1.x. Will be removed soon.
 */
@Deprecated
@IsBoolean
public static final String TOPOLOGY_BACKPRESSURE_ENABLE = "topology.backpressure.enable";
```

Does anyone know how to disable this feature? The purpose is to have a fine-grained control over an experiment and I would like to avoid side effects of this feature.

Any comments/remarks on *automatic back pressure* on Storm will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it outright, but you can make the backpressure checks happen so rarely that it effectively disables the feature. Try setting the `topology.backpressure.check.millis` setting to a large number.

For more context see [the backpressure update code](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/925422a5b5ad1c3329a2c2b44db460ae94f70806/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/daemon/worker/Worker.java#L329), and the [backpressure tracker](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/c78f1aaa8fcd17eb5c8f45f5dbb90e30f99e19bb/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/daemon/worker/BackPressureTracker.java). You can find more information at the JIRA issue for the work done for the new backpressure design [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2306), where there is also a design document for the feature.